# Serverless framework - Enabling X-Ray in serverless.yml

Tags: serverless-framework, serverless, aws-xray

Is there a way to enable X-Ray from the serverless.yml for Lambda functions?
I've added the X-Ray permissions in the file:

```
  iamRoleStatements:
    - Effect: "Allow"
      Resource: "*"
      Action:
        - "xray:*"
```

But Advanced Tracing still needs to be manually enabled in the AWS console.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's [in development](https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3495). If you're unwilling to wait until the official functionality is released, you can [install the plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-plugin-tracing) until it's ready.

Comment: this plugin hasn't been updated for a year and still in beta mode. Does serverless framework support AWS XRay tracing now or this plugin is the only option?

Comment: it's already released, check serverless AWS document here https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/serverless.yml/

Comment: This answer is out of date - don't use the plugin. Do what @ulad-kasach says.

Answer (score 13):

See the serverless documentation:

https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/functions/#aws-x-ray-tracing

```
service: myService

provider:
  name: aws
  runtime: nodejs8.10
  tracing:
    lambda: true
```

See also tracing for api gateway: https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/events/apigateway/#aws-x-ray-tracing

```
# serverless.yml

provider:
  name: aws
  tracing:
    apiGateway: true
```

Comment: Does the apiGateway option only work if the API gateway is created by the serverless framework? I am trying this and the lambda option works ok, but the API gateway option doesnt work, I build my api gateway with terraform. My stage is created by serverless, so I figured it would work.

Answer (score 0):

It is also worth noting that currently X-Ray support is dependent on which type of Aws API is selected. If you chose REST (which by your syntax you did ) X-Ray is supported BUT if someone chooses HTTP it is NOT supported. For reference see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vs-rest.html#http-api-vs-rest.differences.monitoring